# Error while calling sql statement

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am getting an weirded error, I have my code to get data from local db.

My query is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Survey_Details Where feedBack_status="YES"
```

When i fire above query the function gives proper output.But when i pass NO it gives me an error.

Following is my function

```
 -(NSMutableArray*)selectFromDBAndAddtoArrayForFeedbackStatus:(NSString *)feedBackStatus
    {
       NSMutableArray *TableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       sqlite3_stmt    *statement;


    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &passionDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM Survey_Details Where feedBack_status != \"%@\"",feedBackStatus];
        NSLog(@"insert stmnt %@", insertSQL);
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(passionDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"SQLITE_OK");
            if (SQLITE_ROW != sqlite3_step(passionDB))
            {

            }
            else{

            }
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSMutableArray *editTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

                NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

                NSString *surname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

                NSString *time = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 14)];

                // NSString *user_ID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                NSNumber *user_ID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1)];


                [editTableArray addObject:title];
                [editTableArray addObject:name];
                [editTableArray addObject:surname];
                [editTableArray addObject:time];
                [editTableArray addObject:user_ID];

                NSString *imagePath;

                if ([feedBackStatus isEqualToString:@"YES"])
                {

                    if(sqlite3_column_text(statement, 13) != nil)
                    {
                        imagePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char    *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 13)];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imagePath = @"none";
                    }
                    [editTableArray addObject:imagePath];
                }


                [TableArray addObject:editTableArray];
                editTableArray=nil;

            }

            NSLog(@"TableArray1 is %@",TableArray);
        }

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)

        {
            NSLog(@"sqlite is done");
            NSLog(@"Error %s while sqlite3_step ", sqlite3_errmsg(passionDB));
        } else {
            NSLog(@"sqlite is not  done");
            NSLog(@"Error %s while sqlite3_step ", sqlite3_errmsg(passionDB));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(passionDB);
    }
    NSLog(@"TableArray2 is %@",TableArray);
    return TableArray;
    }
```

Comment: are you able to see the data in your database using sqlite broweser? Just to make sure your database contains NO values

Comment: Provide details about the error.

Comment: You should log the error if the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails.

Comment: And what's the point of the line `if (SQLITE_ROW != sqlite3_step(passionDB))`? 1) You can't pass a database pointer to `sqlite3_step`. 2) What is that line supposed to be for?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the query:

```
  NSString *status= @"NO";

NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Survey_Details WHERE feedBack_status ='%@'",status];
```

See if this query works for you.

Comment: Do not build queries using `stringWithFormat`. Properly bind values into the query using the appropriate `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.